# Solvable Lie group stabilizes a flag of projective spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups

By Lie's flag theorem: If $G$ is a connected solvable linear group in $Gl_n(\mathbb C)$, then $G$ stabilizes a full flag of complex subspaces $$\{0\}\subset V_1\subset\dots \subset V_n=\mathbb C^n$$ Now since $\mathbb CP^{n-1}=\mathbb C^{n-1}\sqcup\mathbb C^{n-2}\sqcup\dots \sqcup\mathbb C^1\sqcup\{\infty\}$, so can we deduce that if $G$ is solvable connected Lie group (linear in $Gl_n(\mathbb C)$) then $G$ stabilizes $$\{\infty\} \subset\mathbb CP^1\subset\mathbb CP^2\subset \dots\subset \mathbb CP^{n-1}$$

Is there any example on this situation?

Comment: Isn't this what Borel subgroups are supposed to do?

Comment: It's hard for me to guess what is the question. Examples are stabilizer of full flags, and their subgroup, and these are all examples. What more do you want?